# Spinner background make the title disappear

Tags: android, background, spinner

I have to implement in spinner the same background as in editText but when I put the  property in spinner the title (sector1) and the arrow of disappears. how i can make it to appear?

Code xml of spinner and editText-->

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/registration_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_horizontal_normal"
            android:entries="@array/registration_sector"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_vertical_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/appIntroDefaultPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_vertical_small"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registration_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_horizontal_normal"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLength="16"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_vertical_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/appIntroDefaultPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_vertical_small"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Code of shape -->

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Image of editText and spinner -->

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the background of spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:gravity="right|center" android:src="@drawable/your_spinner_arrow_image" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow at spinner is part of background.
You should use [ninepatch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) to create background of Spinner.

For example background of spinner for xxhdpi:

[image: Spinner's background for xxhdpi]

And my EditText background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <stroke android:color="@color/colorSecondaryText" android:width="2px"/>

    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>

</shape>
```